# Official LINQ Extension Methods

Tags: .net, linq, extension-methods

With .NET 3.5 a large amount of extension methods were added to the core base of code.  I've noticed that in MSDN, IEnumerable<> etc have a section on Extension methods that have been added.

Is there a list of ALL the extension methods that have been added for reference?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answers but I'm looking for a full list, not just links to MSDN articles for each independant type, I'm looking for a full list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of the extension methods for Linq can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).  I don't think there is a comprehensive list of **all** extension methods for .net 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [list with descriptions and examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323215240/https://www.dotnetperls.com/linq).

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation has been updated, and it has icons to indicate what is an extension method and what isn't.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I've seen this list in MSDN but for example I can go to IEnumerable<> as see some of the extension methods and then go to List<> as see others such as ForEach().

Comment: Actually checking this out, ForEach is not an extension method. my fault.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for them yourself using .NET Reflector and the [CodeSearch](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=CodeSearch)
 add-in.